# Resetting plugins due to page load is very slow

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm a application in Ionic and when I build the app and run in my device, when debug the app I show that the loader(splash screen) is very slow, 30seconds more or less... I don't know what happens.. I need help!
Thanks

```
2015-12-01 00:29:23.545 asdasd[3570:1983452] Apache Cordova native platform 

version 3.9.2 is starting.
2015-12-01 00:29:23.547 asdasd[3570:1983452] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2015-12-01 00:29:23.564 asdasd[3570:1983452] Unlimited access to network resources
2015-12-01 00:29:24.166 asdasd[3570:1983452] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 356.240034ms
2015-12-01 00:29:24.189 asdasd[3570:1983452] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 22.265017ms
2015-12-01 00:29:24.190 asdasd[3570:1983452] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.568032ms
2015-12-01 00:29:24.190 asdasd[3570:1983452] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 379.817963ms
2015-12-01 00:29:24.508 asdasd[3570:1983452] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2015-12-01 00:29:55.053 asdasd[3570:1983452] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
```

Comment: Your output above shows the splashscreen loads in about 0.356s?

Comment: yes, but I think that it isn't critical, the critical is :
Resetting plugins due to page load.

the time is 30 seconds... @Huey

Comment: In your question, you identified the problem as the *loader (splash screen)* being very slow. Why are your plugins even resetting for page loads? Aren't you using AngularJS? Are you using routing?

Comment: yes, I don't know if the problem is the 'splash screen', I know that the page is very slow in that moment... I want to say that I generate the splash screen with the ionic generator.. 
and your question, yes,  I use AngularJS(Ionic)  and I use routing (ui-route) 

Thanks @Huey

Comment: If you can share your app code it would help us to identify any problem.

Comment: thanks, I intregrate wkwebview and solve it! thanksss @DavidePastore