# When should wkWebView be used?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, wkwebview

I am using *Cordova* to build a hybrid application. In the app, links do not always work in iOS (no issues on Android). After extensive searches, I found the error "*Resetting plugins due to page load*". I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010220/resetting-plugins-due-to-page-load-is-very-slow#_=_). In order to resolve this, however, we need to use ***WKWebView***, which I installed ([WKWebView plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine)).

Some sites show details of wkWebView, but I am unsure of how or when I should be using ***WKWebView***.

Comment: Isn't WKWebview for watch kit ?

Comment: It's for iphone(hybrid app)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) is WebKit WebView.

Answer (score 1):

WebView is a Web Kit (WK) - in other words it is basically the browser engine (responsible for rendering view, HTML5 functionalities like database etc). Webview should be used if you have an iOS app. By default, iOS uses UIview, which has lot of bugs and issues with Cordova. Webview should fix them, and also improve the performance.

However, WebView installation might be a tricky one. For example, it has no support for WebSQL or indexedDB (and therefore, SQLite should be used for iOS). Also, if you are accessing files via file:// protocol, then you need to install additional plugins that runs local server (https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugins.git#master:local-webserver).
In addition, we don't need it on Android and the localserver settings should be applied only for iOS.

Although it sounds complicated. It is still highly recommended to be installed. Unless you have a very basic app.

In the future, Cordova plans to make WKwebview the default one for iOS (and also for platforms such as [Ionic](https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) etc). Read [this](http://blog.ionic.io/cordova-ios-performance-improvements-drop-in-speed-with-wkwebview/).

I hope I answered to the point.

Source: [my own](https://www.linkedin.com/in/guyromb) experience with hybrid apps